# return $request->input() is returning nothing on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am sorry it might seem very silly but I really don't know where the problem is, I am working on a register page and I am trying to see if i can get the requested input but when I use return `$request->input()` it gives me an empty token with no values of the input :

```
{"_token":"f6Ohhsz5RsWe1NAf0QC8uI5YcopXf5ug2jHqF5u6"}
```

here's the function I am using in the controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request->input();

}
```

and these are the routes I am using for the register page :

```
Route::get('/register', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@register') ->name('register');

Route::post('/store', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@store')->name('store');
```

please I need some help !!

Comment: You may retrieve all of the incoming request's input data as an array using the `all` method. `$return $request->all();` You may call the `query` method without any arguments in order to retrieve all of the query string values as an associative array: `return $request->query();`

Answer (score 0):

return $request->all();

you can request all data.

Comment: when input() can you add all your field on request